# Moving Posts to a new site and maintaining URLs

Tags: posts, urls, import, seo, export

I am looking to move all my posts to a new site. The new site is sitting in a dev environment and will eventually be launched in place of the new site at the same URL.

The blog posts will not have the same structure however. The old site URL structure is `www.example.com/blog` and the new site will not have the `/blog`. It will just be `www.example.com/my-post-example`

I have tried using the export/import tool but I am having trouble with the URLs after. After importing the URLs have the default WordPress URL with numbers and question marks and when I manually change the permalink they have this at the end `www.example.com/my-post-example#.UpMsHo1hA6I`.

Does anyone know the how I should be going about this so that I minimize the SEO impact of all the posts created?

Comment: Disable all plugins and switch to the default theme. Does it still happen?

Comment: How about if you change in the database. In 'wp-options' table, you can customize siteurl & homeurl.

Comment: Unfortunately at the moment I do not have ftp access as it is an agency doing the site for us and they havn't handed over the ftp details yet. Also they have removed the default themes and I can't install it. I figure this is going to be pretty difficult (near on impossible) to solve with out having ftp access!? Might have to wait. Thanks for the suggestions though will keep note for when I get full access.